# Isotope callback not happening after window resize

Tags: callback, resize, jquery-isotope

I need to run a script after window get resized and isotope finish operating.
I thought callbacks would help but they're not fired in case of window resize.

As I need the updated container 's width value after resize, is there another way ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

this worked..

[docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#onlayout)

Similiar to a callback, onLayout is a function that will be triggered after every time an Isotope instance runs through its layout logic.

```
$('#container').isotope({
  onLayout: function( $elems, instance ) {
    // `this` refers to jQuery object of the container element
    console.log( this.height() );
    // callback provides jQuery object of laid-out item elements
    $elems.css({ background: 'blue' });
    // instance is the Isotope instance
    console.log( instance.$filteredAtoms.length );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i was looking into that eather and couldnt find a solution. so i picked this *ugly* one:

```
$(window).smartresize(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        //your function
    }, 810);
});
```

so on resize i set a timeout that calls 810ms after isotope relayout, which should take 800ms in jquery, or 0.8s in css3.
like is said, its ugly, but for now i fits the purpose..